# Do we need to release an UIImage object even not allocated memory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

I added an image to button

```
UIImage* deleteImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Delete.png"];
CGRect imageFrame=CGRectMake(-4,-4, 310, 55);
[btn setFrame:imageFrame];
btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[btn setBackgroundImage:deleteImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self  action:@selector(editDeleteAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[elementView addSubview:btn];
[deleteImage release];// do we need to release the image here
```

If I release here its working fine but in object allocations no.of image count is increasing.

Comment: i suggest that you get up to speed on Cocoa/Cocoa Touch memory management: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create an image with the imageNamed: message you don't have to release it, because you get an autoreleased image back.

Only if you create the image with one of the init...: messages you have to release it later on.

Comment: That is the case with ANY object that you instantiate with `init` - you own it, therefore you must release it.

Comment: Its more a case of any object that is created new (not necessarily instantiated) using any of the CARN rule methods. That is to say that any methods that contain the words Copy, Alloc, Retain or New should return an object with a retain count of +1 and are owned by the caller and should be released at some point. Anything else is assumed to return an autoreleased object.

Comment: For further information look at the iPhone memory management guide in the apple documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/

Answer (score 0):

"**imageNamed**:" method gives an *autoreleased* object, so you don't have to release object.

*FYI*: "**imageNamed**:" method uses an internal cache (you may face memory warning if imageNamed: method used extensively). It is better to remove cache on receiving warnings.

```
- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[ImageCache sharedImageCache] removeAllImagesInMemory];
}
```

Go through this guide http://akosma.com/2009/01/28/10-iphone-memory-management-tips/

Comment: The imageNamed: cache problem has been solved since iPhone OS 3.0. It is, however, a real issue if your app has to work with any of the 2.x versions...